# Integral of a function of phi and sin(phi) in denominator

Tags: integration

I need to solve an integral for my master thesis in physics, but I do not know how to even start. The integral is

$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{b+\sin^2(\phi)} \cdot \frac{1}{a^2+\phi^2} d\phi$

Both a and b are positive and bigger than 0, so the integral should converge.

I tried to think of a Weierstrass Substitution, but could not find a suitable one.

Also, I could not apply the Residue theorem, since I do not know which contours to use.

I need the result dependent on a and b.

Can you give me any tipps?

Comment: Looks nasty! I don't see any way other than doing it numerically unfortunately.